# Preventing the most common attacks with firewalld on CentOS 7

Tags: centos

I have seen countless iptables tutorials where you can configure your iptables to prevent the most common attacks. But the only tutorials I have been able to find on firewalld is how to enable and disable traffic for ssh, http, https, smtp and so on. Is it so that firewalld has built in defence against most common attacks?

For example statements like these are used as a basic protection against bots, and null packets, syn flood attack.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
```

But I have not been able to find these kinds of things for firewalld. Is it prebuilt in firewalld?

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on the Internet. None of this is necessary for Red Hat-based systems using either firewalld or the previous system-config-firewall utilities, as all such traffic is already blocked.

Comment: Oh ok. So I should not worry about anything else than just allowing things like http, https, ssh, smtp  on firewalld then?

Comment: Right. Firewalld is default-deny, like any good firewall (and UNlike the tutorials you've been reading).

Comment: What about such rules in iptables to prevent DDoS? -> [IPtables DDoS Protection](https://javapipe.com/iptables-ddos-protection)